# Universal File Format

Tags: python

Estoy intentado importar en OpenModal datos de sensores (galgas extensométricas) la información debe importarse a través de la libreria pyuff.  Estos son los parámatros que estoy introduciendo:

```
for i in range(4):
    print('Adding point {:}'.format(i + 1))
    response_node = 1
    response_direction = 1
    reference_node = i + 1
    reference_direction = 1
    strain_real = dataSensor[i]
    time
    name = 'TestCase'
    data = {'type':58, 
            'func_type':1, 
            'rsp_node': i+1, 
            'rsp_dir': 3, 
            'ref_dir': 3, 
            'ref_node': i+1,
            'data': strain_real,
            'x': time,
            'id1': 'id1', 
            'rsp_ent_name': name,
            'ref_ent_name': name,
            'abscissa_spacing':1,
            'abscissa_spec_data_type':17,
            'ordinate_spec_data_type':3,
            'orddenom_spec_data_type':13}
    uffwrite = pyuff.UFF('./data/measurement.uff')
    uffwrite._write_set(data,'add')
```

Algunos de los parametros deben ser incorrectos ya que los valores que muestra el programa no son correctos.

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! ¿Te sale algun error o has investigado la posible causa? Si es asi agregalo para facilitarle la labor de ayuda a los usuarios. Un saludo :)

Comment: Gracias Capt.Teach, sigo tratando de cifrar los datos en este código. Es algo sencillo para quien ha trabajado una sola vez con este formato y python. Saludos